# Debian buster and libgfortran3

Tags: debian-buster

I want to install 3rd party software that requires libgfortran3. I have a fresh install of Debian 10 (Buster). On Buster only libgfortran4 and higher is available, how can I install libgfortran3 without getting complaints from apt?